# How to disable pytest dumping out source code?

Tags: python, pytest

When one of the tests fail, pytest will dump out the source code of the function where the exception is raised. However, something when the error is raised from another library, it still dumps the function source code flood the output.

Is it possible to disable pytest from dump source code and have the stack trace only? Stack trace is usually more than enough to track down the problem.

I have searched a bit but all I can find are posts related to `--show-capture`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `--tb` option. You can choose either `--tb=short` or `--tb=native` as per what suits you. Check the detailed documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/output.html#modifying-python-traceback-printing).

Comment: Thank you. I have search that page with `Source code`  and similar words but I could not find it.

Comment: I can't find a way to indicate this in `pytest.ini`, would it be possible at all ?

Comment: @ArnaudP I've added another answer, showing how to do this in `purest.ini`

Answer (score 10):

Here is how to put your chosen option in a `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
# --tb not given    Produces reams of output, with full source code included in tracebacks
# --tb=no           Just shows location of failure in the test file: no use for tracking down errors
# --tb=short        Just shows vanilla traceback: very useful, but file names are incomplete and relative
# --tb=native       Slightly more info than short: still works very well. The full paths may be useful for CI
addopts = --tb=native
```

The available values for `--tb` are:

```
  --tb=style            traceback print mode
                        (auto/long/short/line/native/no).
```

Useful links:

- [pytest Configuration file formats](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#configuration-file-formats)
- [pytest Command-line Flags](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#command-line-flags)